# Docker 1.12 on Mac issue with DB connection pool

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-machine

We have a web application running inside docker container with Jboss as the application server. Everything works fine with the docker container running on Linux machine.
But when we run the same image with DC container running on MAC, DB connection pool related issue starts coming. On Mac even stopping and removing container doesn't release the DB connections.  Eventually it consumes all available connections. The only solution at that time is to restart the Docker Daemon.
Although this doesn't happen all the time but occurs very frequently. Almost everyday we hit this issue.
We have DB MIN POOL AND MAX POOL settings added in JBoss standlone.xml.

Docker version: 1.12.
Mac os version: OSX EL Capitan, version 10.11

Any help or suggestion in this area would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is your database in another container on the same docker daemon?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, we use a centralized DB. Which has a hostname and port to connect along with proper credentials. We add these entries in standalone.xml file of Jboss. Thus Jboss connects to the DB.